# Changing saved file names R

Tags: r

I'm using the following code:

```
lst <- split(data, cut(data$Pos, breaks = maxima, include.lowest = TRUE))
dir <- getwd()
lapply(seq_len(length(lst)),
       function (i) write.csv(lst[[i]], file = paste0(dir,"/",names(lst[i]),    ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)) ## split data into .csv files based on max.csvima values
```

that another user provided me with, to split and save a dataset into separate .csv files. However, when the files are saved they are saved in a naming format as so: [0,9], (9,19], etc., which the analysis program I'm using cannot read in. How would I change the filenames that they are being saved as? I assumed that it was the

```
names(lst[i])
```

portion, however when I changed that (e.g. to names(vec[i]) with vec being a vector of numbers with the same length as the number of data files), no data files were created.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: how do you want the final file names to be? you could list them out in order by simply replacing `paste0(dir,"/",names(lst[i])` with something like `paste0(dir,"/split_dataset_",[i],".csv")`

Comment: those are the default labels created by `cut` since you did not provide any labels. Since you are splitting based on that factor, the list elements will be named by the unique values created in `cut`

Comment: @desc, doing so gives me this error: Error: unexpected '[' in:
"lapply(seq_len(length(lst)),
       function (i) write.csv(lst[[i]], file = paste0(dir,"/split_dataset_",["

Comment: @rawr, how would I modify the  cut code to have different labels?

Answer (score 0):

@desc provides the answer in the comment you only need to change your code to

```
lst <- split(data, cut(data$Pos, breaks = maxima, include.lowest = TRUE))
dir <- getwd()
lapply(seq_len(length(lst)),
   function (i) write.csv(lst[[i]], file = paste0(dir,"/your_desired_label_here",names(lst[i]),    ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)) ## split data into .csv files based on max.csvima values
```

Comment: The program I am trying to import the files into does not accept brackets or parentheses in the file names, so this solution doesn't work as the file names will still contain those characters. Is there a way to modify the original cut code to change the naming format?

Comment: @GeorgeSBF, could you provide with a brief example of your data and what do you want to achieve so I can update the code?